# Script for Running Program from Command Line

Tags: linux, shell

I am new to Linux so please excuse my ignorance:

On my current work machine if I type:

```
$ matlab
```

...the machine is configured so that matlab is executed.

I want to do the same thing for ImageJ ...i.e. typing:

```
$ ImageJ
```

so that ImageJ is executed. This would be helpful as it is annoying to go into the directory and typing `./run`

Answer (score 2):

First make sure your `run` file is executable by using the **chmod** command: `chmod +x run`.

Then you should create a symbolic link using the **ln** command which would have the ImageJ binary (the file named `run`) as the target and `/usr/local/bin/ImageJ` as the destination.

The `/usr/local/bin/` directory is most likely already in your PATH variable (`echo $PATH`).

When done type use `source /etc/profile` to update your current **bash** session (assuming you use bash) and you can now type `ImageJ` to launch it from any path (see the **pwd** command).

NB: Note the words in bold, those are commands and you can find more infos on them using **man** like this: `man chmod`. Have fun !

Answer (score 0):

You need either to provide the full path to the executable to run it, or you put the directory containing the executable(s) in your `PATH` variable in order to run it as a regular command.

Using the full path you simply do:

```
 $ /path/to/imagej/run
```

To add the directory to your path, add the following to ỳour `~/.bashrc` file:

```
PATH=$PATH:/path/to/imagej/
```

Source the changes made to that file with `source ~/.bashrc` and remember to edit these paths to the real ones on your system, accordingly. Now you should be able to run the command `run` to start it. Possibly rename the `run` file to something more comprehensible.

Answer (score 0):

Consider renaming the executable as suggested by one of the other answers.  A caveat to using the `PATH` environmental variable to find an executable is that the listed directories will be searched until the first match of your executable is found.  A generic name like `run` might cause a conflict.

A handy sanity check for which executable is actually being run is to execute `which run`, which will output the absolute path to the executable found by searching the `PATH` directories.  To see the order of directories searched, which is the definition of PATH, execute `echo $PATH`

Welcome to Linux!